# Multi-value selection in an Excel cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, data-validation

There's a way to make an Excel cell kind of a dropdown selection box. You would just go to Data->Validation with a cell or a range of cell selected, select list as the data type and specify the list of values.

I would like the dropdown be a multi value select, kind of a multi value lookup. 
I suppose there's no built in support for that, but there may be some third party solutions utilizing the macro capabilities. Googling gave me an example of such a macro but it is far from the experience of a real multi value lookup when you just mark the selected items with check boxes to the left or select the values in a kind of a popup window. (You would select the items needed from a single-value dopdown ny sequentially selecting each item and the macro would populate an adjacent range of cells with the selected values, putting every value in a new cell).

**What's is the most native looking way to make a multi-selection cell in Excel?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See the Forms section in Excel Help for the topic "Add a list box or combo box to a worksheet".

From that page (referring to a Form control list box):

> Note: If you set the selection type to
>   Multi or Extend, the cell that is
>   specified in the Cell link box returns
>   a value of 0 and is ignored. The Multi
>   and Extend selection types require the
>   use of Microsoft Visual Basic for
>   Applications (VBA) code. In these
>   cases, consider using the ActiveX list
>   box control.

And referring to an ActiveX control list box:

> To create a list box with multiple
>   selection or extended-selection
>   enabled, use the MultiSelect property.
>   In this case, the LinkedCell property
>   returns a #N/A value. You must use VBA
>   code to process the multiple
>   selections.

Comment: Thanks! Will have a look. Don't have enough rep to upvote yet :(